# How to use value from one field to validate other field in JOI schema

Tags: node.js, validation, backend, joi

I am trying to create schema using JOI custom.

The body model:

```
const type body = {
level: number;
statistics: Array<{
name: string;
value: number;
}>;
}
```

I want the statistics value to be less than level multiplied by certain value.
At the same time I want to keep all the basic validation rules.

My schema looks something like that now:

```
const StatisticsValidator = Joi.object().keys({
level: Joi.number().required().min(1),
statistics: Joi.array.items(Joi.object().keys({
type: Joi.string(),
value: Joi.number().required().custom((statValue) => {
          Joi.ref('level', {
          adjust: (levelValue) => {
    console.log(levelValue;
    }}}),
 });
```

For now I am just trying to print the level value so I know I can use it to calculate my maximum, because many previous approach didn't work, but then how can I use it?

I was trying to use Joi.custom directly on statistics also when using Joi.ref I tried to refer to level field with "$" and "...", I read Joi documentation regarding custom, ref, objects, method etc ( https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0#anycustommethod-description ), I watched tutorials on YT and still I don't know how to use the level value.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
const StatisticsValidator = Joi.object().keys({
 level: Joi.number().required().min(1),
 statistics: Joi.array.items(Joi.object().keys({
  type: Joi.string(),
  value: Joi.number().max(Joi.ref('....level', { adjust: (levelValue) => {
      console.error(levelValue) }).required(),          
     }}}),
 });
```

1. Turned out I needed to use 4 dots in front of the referenced field name.
2. I used `console.error` to display the value
3. I used `.max()` because ultimately I wanted to validate the maximum value of the value field.
4. Initially I was going to use `.custom()` because someone gave me a hint that in this situation the object, with all its fields, will be passed to the method and then I will be able to ref to the field I want.